# JavaFX question on terms "target" and "source"

Tags: java, javafx

I am hoping you can help clarify something for me. I believe I understand the author's treatment of event handling in JavaFX up until he stated the following (Eck, 2022, Section 6.3.1):

“The object that the listener is registered with is called the source of the event”.

Isn't it the "target" that we register the listener objects with? And sometimes the target and source can be the same. The source is component that generates the event objects.

Edit: Thanks everyone! I tested this and it seems that these terms in JavaFX are kind of backwards. This is modified from example in book. The target is the button (!) which emits the event and the source (the HBox container) detects them!

[image]

References:

Eck, D. J. (2022). Introduction to programming using Java, version 9.0. http://math.hws.edu/javanotes

Comment: Most of these questions can be answered by reading the docs: [MouseEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html)  In this case it tells me that there's a `getSource()` method but no `getTarget()` method.  Your Eck book is being fairly fast and loose with the API, you might try looking around for a better guide.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html

Comment: @markspace, [getTarget()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/Event.html#getTarget--)

Comment: That's Event, not MouseEvent.  The source book is mixing Swing and JavaFx classes.  It's not a great idea.

Comment: a good resource for learning fx event processing is the ol' tutorial - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/events.htm#JFXED117 ... also, don't forget to study the api doc (as @mrmcwolf already suggested) , it's a bit dense at places but correct

Comment: I'll try to put it simply: `source` can be **anything** (the source of the event), `target` its receiver (javafx node), and `listener`s can register anywhere along the chain from the root node to the target and back.

Comment: Thanks very much, for this. I think the book was correct that the source according to the following test which i will attempt to paste as an answer. In JavaFX, the target emits the events and the source detects them. If this is correct, it is completely backwards from what my experience with web apis would lead me to believe.

Comment: repeating: please study the basic description of fx event handling - I believe that there is no way to fully understand the concept of source/target in fx context - they are the _positions_ of the event in the dispatch chain, in particular: source == _Origin of the event, with respect to the location of the event in the event dispatch chain_ and target == _Node on which the action occurred and the end node in the event dispatch chain_ The former changes while being delivered along the chain, the latter remains the same but might never be reached.

Comment: Please don’t screenshot code, put it in the question as text, formatted as code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Events in JavaFX have a target, but they don't necessarily *start* at the target. They travel from the top of the scene graph towards the target and then travel back up. The travelling down phase is known as the "capturing phase", while the travelling up phase is known as the "bubbling phase".

Capturing phase:

```
Window → Scene → Root Layout → Layout 1 → Layout 2 → Target Node
```

Bubbling phase:

```
Window ← Scene ← Root Layout ← Layout 1 ← Layout 2 ← Target Node
```

What this means is that `EventHandler`s, or even the same `EventHandler`, can be registered at any point along this path/chain. Throughout the entire process, the *target* remains the same. But the *source* changes as the event travels, so that it is always the `Window` / `Scene` / `Node` that is *currently processing* the event. You can see this with the following code:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    private int indent;
    private final EventHandler<Event> filter = event -> {
        System.out.printf(
                "%ssource = %s, target = %s%n",
                " ".repeat(indent),
                event.getSource(),
                event.getTarget()
        );
        if (event.getSource() != event.getTarget()) {
            indent += 4;
        } else {
            System.out.println(" ".repeat(indent) + "CAPTURING PHASE COMPLETE -- BUBBLING PHASE STARTING");
        }
    };
    private final EventHandler<Event> handler = event -> {
        System.out.printf(
                "%ssource = %s, target = %s%n",
                " ".repeat(indent),
                event.getSource(),
                event.getTarget()
        );
        indent -= 4;
    };

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button targetNode = new Button("Click me!");
        targetNode.addEventFilter(ActionEvent.ACTION, filter);
        targetNode.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, handler);
        targetNode.setId("targetNode");

        StackPane layoutTwo = new StackPane(targetNode);
        layoutTwo.addEventFilter(ActionEvent.ACTION, filter);
        layoutTwo.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, handler);
        layoutTwo.setId("layoutTwo");

        StackPane layoutOne = new StackPane(layoutTwo);
        layoutOne.addEventFilter(ActionEvent.ACTION, filter);
        layoutOne.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, handler);
        layoutOne.setId("layoutOne");

        StackPane rootLayout = new StackPane(layoutOne);
        rootLayout.addEventFilter(ActionEvent.ACTION, filter);
        rootLayout.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, handler);
        rootLayout.setId("rootLayout");

        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout, 500, 300);
        scene.addEventFilter(ActionEvent.ACTION, filter);
        scene.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, handler);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.addEventFilter(ActionEvent.ACTION, filter);
        primaryStage.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, handler);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Output (when you click the button):

```
source = javafx.stage.Stage@7a23cddd, target = Button[id=targetNode, styleClass=button]'Click me!'
    source = javafx.scene.Scene@67d7e678, target = Button[id=targetNode, styleClass=button]'Click me!'
        source = StackPane[id=rootLayout, styleClass=root], target = Button[id=targetNode, styleClass=button]'Click me!'
            source = StackPane[id=layoutOne], target = Button[id=targetNode, styleClass=button]'Click me!'
                source = StackPane[id=layoutTwo], target = Button[id=targetNode, styleClass=button]'Click me!'
                    source = Button[id=targetNode, styleClass=button]'Click me!', target = Button[id=targetNode, styleClass=button]'Click me!'
                    CAPTURING PHASE COMPLETE -- BUBBLING PHASE STARTING
                    source = Button[id=targetNode, styleClass=button]'Click me!', target = Button[id=targetNode, styleClass=button]'Click me!'
                source = StackPane[id=layoutTwo], target = Button[id=targetNode, styleClass=button]'Click me!'
            source = StackPane[id=layoutOne], target = Button[id=targetNode, styleClass=button]'Click me!'
        source = StackPane[id=rootLayout, styleClass=root], target = Button[id=targetNode, styleClass=button]'Click me!'
    source = javafx.scene.Scene@67d7e678, target = Button[id=targetNode, styleClass=button]'Click me!'
source = javafx.stage.Stage@7a23cddd, target = Button[id=targetNode, styleClass=button]'Click me!'
```

As you can see, the source changes but the target remains the same.

Note that event "filters" are invoked during the capturing phase, whereas event "handlers" are invoked during the bubbling phase. An `EventHandler` that's registered via one of the `onXXX` properties are also invoked during the bubbling phase.

Comment: Also worth noting is that, if anything consumes the event in either of the phases, it stops traveling at that point and cannot be seen by later handlers or filters that would have been triggered in the chain.  This can be the reason that sometimes a developer does not see an event they expected (something else already consumed the event).